# Sending input from Textbox

Tags: textbox, user-input

I have a textbox on my C# WPF project and I want it to send the value inputted into the textbox to a variable into the following function once i press enter.

Does my user input from my textbox have to be in a separate function or can I have it within the same function I want to have the value sent to?

```
    private void UserInput(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        Point p1 = new Point();
        TextBox textBoxX = new TextBox();
        if (e.Key == Key.Enter)
        {
            double inputAsNumberX = 0.0000;
            if (double.TryParse(textBoxX.Text, out inputAsNumberX))
            {
                p1.X = inputAsNumberX;
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("This is not a number.");
            }

        }
        else
        {
        }

        double inputAsNumberY = 0;
        TextBox textBoxY = sender as TextBox;
        while (textBoxY.Text == null)
        {
            //textBoxY = sender as TextBox;
        }
        if (double.TryParse(textBoxY.Text, out inputAsNumberY) == true)
        {
            p1.X = inputAsNumberY;
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("This is not a number.");
        }


    }
```

xaml code

```
<TextBox Name="TextBoxX" TextWrapping="Wrap" MaxLength="32" KeyDown="UserInput" />
```

Update:  strange thing i have a question about is that when i try enter anything (while debugging), it stops me from entering anything. after running through the code, and trying to enter again, it allows me to enter one char (like a number) and then stops me from entering more.

it also seems that it only shows the new char typed in the textbox after the code is run.

how can i fix my code to run the way i want, which is to enter a value, press enter, value gets sent to function, which sets it to the double variable: inputAsNumberX???

Update 2:
I have updated with the code I am using. I am trying to get two inputs so I set up two textboxes. Both should do the same thing as I asked above.

Comment: I dont know if what I am trying to do in my code above is how to get what i type in, in the textbox, to be sent to variable inputAsNumberX

Comment: The call to double.TryParse should parse the value entered into the textbox and set the variable inputAsNumberX to that value.  Try debugging and see what the variable inputAsNumberX is set to after the call to double.TryParse.

Comment: IS having the KeyDown="UserInput" needed? for some reason when I set the Textbox KeyDown event to reference the UserInput function, when i type anything into the box it automatically goes straight to function. I want it to go when I press enter.

Comment: when I debug, inputAsNumberX does not change, it changes only after i run through the code once, and it allows me to enter something into the textbox (a second time). but it only allows me to enter 1 character. i have updated my original post above with this.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, you have set the UserInput function as a handler for the `KeyDown` eventhandler on your textbox.  This means that every time you press a key with the textbox selected the UserInput function will be called.  If you only want to parse the contents of the textbox when 'Enter' is pressed, you can change your code to the following:

```
private void UserInput(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key == Key.Enter)
    {
        var textBox = sender as TextBox;
        if (textBox != null)
        {
            double inputAsNumberX = 0;

            if (double.TryParse(textBox.Text, out inputAsNumberX))
            {
                // Do something with inputAsNumberX here.
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("This is not a number.");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note that I start by checking if 'Enter' was pressed.

**UPDATE:**

I changed the code above so that it will work for any textbox using `UserInput` as event handler for the `KeyDown` event.  Use the following XAML for your two textboxes:

```
<TextBox Name="TextBoxX" TextWrapping="Wrap" MaxLength="32" KeyDown="UserInput" />
<TextBox Name="TextBoxY" TextWrapping="Wrap" MaxLength="32" KeyDown="UserInput" />
```

Comment: now i get the first key i press, it automatically goes to "This is not a number." cant even type anything

Comment: @user1773489: If you are getting the message "This is not a number", you did not copy my code as it is.  Try leaving the XAML unchanged and copy my code exactly as it is.

Comment: I did use your code and keep the .xaml the same. still same problem (goes to "This is not a number". When I debug, it for some reason senses I press a key (for example 5, and says e.Key = D5) and stops me from typing and automatically goes through the next lines of code, pass the if statement and to the end of the function. Do I need to change something so it allows me to continue typing first until I press enter and then continues going through the next lines of code that include the if statement?

Comment: @user1773489: There are several errors in your code.  First of all you are creating a new TextBox object which means you are parsing the text of the wrong TextBox.  Second, you do not have to write code for both TextBoxX and TextBoxY as long as you are using "UserInput" for both textboxes in your XAML.  See my updated answer above.